# Sub menu alignment with Superfish jQuery menu

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am using [this Superfish menu](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples). The rightmost main menu has submenus and the submenus hang beyond the container (which is not looking good).

Is there a way to right align the submenu for the last right main menu?

Answer (score 1):

This will right align all sub-menus

```
ul.sf-menu li:hover ul,
ul.sf-menu li.sfHover ul,
ul.sf-menu li ul
{
    right: 0px;
    left: auto;
}
```

To right align just the last one with id="lastitemid" (disclaimer: I haven't tested this)

CSS

```
ul.sf-menu li:hover ul#lastitemid,
ul.sf-menu li.sfHover ul#lastitemid,
ul.sf-menu li ul#lastitemid
{
    right: 0px;
    left: auto;
}
```